# Wordpress, change search.php page layout

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a friend site where He has created page layout to list posts.

All examples I have seen about search always submit to home page, is is possible to change?

I know default page layout is search.php how can I use another one?

I have created a searchform.php file and have tried changing the url in the action, but search does not work. I guess a filter or action missing?

This is the code for searchform:

```html
<form id="searchform" role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink(get_page_by_title('Blog'))); ?>">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="input-medium span8" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Type something', 'placeholder' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="search-box" />
        <input type='hidden' name='page_id' value='111'>
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="btn btn-flat btn-colo" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

If In action I set home url, it works, but if I use another page url it does not.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You'll need to build a custom results search page or add the query functionality to the blog page that you're trying to submit to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page